# Why don't my audio.conf settings cause me to get an unlimited value for ulimit -l?

Tags: memory, ulimit

I am attempting to set the relevant resource limits for some low-latency audio work. I have created an `audio` group, and I believe that I am in that group based on the following:

```
~$ groups
kevin adm sudo audio
```

I have the following set in `/etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf`:

```
@audio   -  rtprio     95
@audio   -  memlock    unlimited
@audio   -  nice      -19
```

However, when I check to see the limits on how much memory I can lock, I get this:

```
$ ulimit -l
65536
```

This is preventing me from running my desired applications, which need to lock down ~1000x this much memory. **I would like the output to be `unlimited` instead. Does anyone have advice for fixing this issue?**

Other notes:

- I am running Pop OS 19.
- I have logged out / back in since setting my `audio.conf`, no change.
- I am fairly inexperienced with this corner of linux, so no explanation is too basic.

Finally, here is the contents of my `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
kevin            soft    rtprio          90
kevin            soft    memlock         unlimited

@audio           hard    rtprio          95
@audio           hard    memlock          unlimited
```